# FileReader buffer different from different safari

Tags: ios, node.js, safari, socket.io, buffer

I have two iPhones who upload jpg files to Node.js server via websockets with help of socket.io like this

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
    socket.emit(
        'chat_file',
        {
            body: reader.result
        }
    );
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(uploadedFile);
```

Problem is if all modern browser upload looks like this on Node.js side

```
Oct 04 11:01:01 test-chat1.bnk.ef.lan node[30130]: { name: 'image2.jpg',
Oct 04 11:01:01 test-chat1.bnk.ef.lan node[30130]: body: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 f0 00 f0 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03 03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05 08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07 07 06 ... >,
Oct 04 11:01:01 test-chat1.bnk.ef.lan node[30130]: size: 95712 } }
```

File body is a buffer, on old iPhone 4, with Safari version 8 i am getting

```
Oct 04 11:00:25 test-chat1.bnk.ef.lan node[30088]: { room: '1','image.jpg', body: { byteLength: 889942 }, size: 889942 } }
```

here body type is not a buffer, i've tried **Buffer.alloc()** and **Buffer.from()** but no luck (logically), in case of **from** i am getting

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
```

and in case of **alloc** it is

```
TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer
```

p.s. On client side on both old and new version of safari **reader.result** is typeof **ArrayBuffer** but old safari have slice method in it

[image]

p.p.s But **ArrayBuffers** body are different (old safari on the right side)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reason was simple, old Safari doesn't send file body over WebSockets, so server side you will just get event about file being send, but without file actually.